# Using reactive repository during bean initialization - do I need to block()?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'd like to create a `JavaMailSender` bean in Spring 5, reading the properties from a reactive database.

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
   JavaMailSender javaMailSender = new JavaMailSender();

   Settings settings = settingsRepository.findByXXX().block(); //returns Mono<Settings> -> Settings after blocking
   //copy stuff from settings to javaMailSender

   return javaMailSender;
}
```

Is there any other way than blocking to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should totally avoid using `.block()` in Spring-Webflux or anykind of reactive framework. By blocking, you will do nothing else than blocking the current thread, so you will produce an overkill of the application. Instead of blocking you can use functions like `.map()` or `.flatMap()` and handle the object inside the mono in a reactive manner.

**EDIT**

```
@Bean
    public Mono<JavaMailSender> javaMailSender() {
        return settingsRepository.findByXXX().flatMap(settings -> {

            if(something) {
                return Mono.just(new JavaMailSender());
            } else {
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException());
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post an example how to create the bean?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I can create Mono objects which then can be autowired. I'll try this, thanks!

Comment: One drawback is that the Autowiring does not unwrap the object so I have to use it like Mono<JavaMailSender> everywhere.

Comment: This is not necessary in the current version of Spring Framework (5.3.19).